# find -printf work around

Tags: command-line, bash, script

I'm trying to use a script to call compare file size. Unfortunately the version of `find` on my mac does not support the `-printf` switch. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider install GNU find using [homebrew](http://brew.sh).

To install homebrew you just need to type the following in your terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install `findutils` by typing:

```
brew install findutils
```

Then your `find` version will support the `-printf` and should be the latest:

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
, nc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
, o the extent permitted by law.

, nd Kevin Dalley.
Built using GNU gnulib version e5573b1bad88bfabcda181b9e0125fb0c52b7d3b
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS() CBO(level=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. For me homebrew prepends 'g' to the find command.

Comment: @acornblue the "g" is for GNU

Comment: Yes, brew will install `GNU find` as `gfind` by default. This is a good thing so that it doesn't break other things that are expecting mac's version of `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Use exec option with 'wc -c' for size in bytes or 'du' for the disk blocks:

```
$ find . -name bill\* -exec wc -c {} + 2>/dev/null
8496 ./bill
 341 ./bill.c
 274 ./bill.c~
9111 total
$ find . -name bill\* -exec du {} + 2>/dev/null   
24  ./bill
8   ./bill.c
8   ./bill.c~
```